# Nested Forms Unknown attribute: question_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have the two models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

And the below controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @question = Question.new  
    4.times { @question.answers.build }
  end

end
```

When i try to load the `new.html.haml` view I'm getting this error:

`Unknown attribute: question_id`

The view look like below:

```
= simple_form_for @question do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.simple_fields_for :answers do |a|
    = a.input :text
  = f.submit
```

Comment: It seems like you forgot to create question_id field in Answers table. There is 1-M relationship between your two models. Make sure you have foreign_key question_id present in Answers table.

Comment: you are completely right, thanks.

Comment: I just added the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to create `question_id` field in Answers table.

There is 1-M relationship between your two models `Question and Answer`. Make sure you have foreign_key `question_id` present in Answers table.